# AWK: Mysql: like query with \newline

Tags: mysql, awk, newline, sql-like

I have this mysql query and I want to use it in an awk command:

```
select * from table where column like '%\n%';
```

this is my awk command:

```
mysql database -N -e "select info from table;" | awk -F ' ' '{ system("mysql -h "$1" table -N -e \"select * from table where column like '%\n%' ;\"")}'
```

Its not working. The part with '%\n%' does not work like it should. Does anyone know how to use it here?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
... system( "mysql -h " $1 " table -N -e \42select * from table where column like \47%\\n%\47 ;\42")
```